# Maximo 7.1 XSLT unable to reprocess transformed message from message reprocessing

Tags: xslt, maximo

I am facing problem while doing message reprocessing in maximo.

Actually I have created a xsl to convert original message (associated in publish channel) into JSON format and it throws an error while processing into endpoint url. Then corrected the url and trying to reprocess the error message from message reprocessing application. Now it is throwing an error that org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

> at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:504) at
>   org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:807) at
>   psdi.iface.util.XMLUtils.convertBytesToDocument(XMLUtils.java:278) at
>   psdi.iface.app.interror.MaxIntErrorMsg.process(MaxIntErrorMsg.java:211)
>   at
>   psdi.iface.app.interror.MaxIntErrorSet.doProcess(MaxIntErrorSet.java:196)
>   at
>   psdi.iface.app.interror.MaxIntErrorSet.process(MaxIntErrorSet.java:161)
>   at
>   psdi.iface.app.interror.MaxIntErrorSet.processSelected(MaxIntErrorSet.java:145)
>   at
>   psdi.webclient.beans.interror.InterrorAppBean.PROCESSSEL(InterrorAppBean.java:28
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

I noticed that the message content in message reprocessing contains XSL converted message. But maximo trying to convert the message from xml onwards, but the message was already converted into json format.

Please advise. Thanks in advance!

Enviornment: Maximo 7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually If I manually process the message it throws an error. After correcting the endpoint url and dont do any manual process in message reprocessing, maximo automatically processing the message.